# no hot water or cold water after installing faucts

Tags: water-heater

Ok all i did was i added to the end of the hot and cold water lines about 3 feet of copper line on each hot and cold water to install a washer .I turned off the main but didnt drain the hot water heater just turned off the breaker . added the plumbing and then turned on main and turned on breaker . The washing machine works fine hot and cold water the sink near by works fine also hot and cold water . The problem is there is another bathroom near by and the sink doesnt work now no hot or cold comes out nothing . There is a toilet in that bathroom and it works fine . Why would the bathroom sink no longer get any water ( cold or hot water) .I tryed  a couple of times turning main off and on again and nothing . like i said the other sink and washing machine work fine and so does toilet in that bathroom but no water at all comes out of sink hot or cold . And i never shut off angle stops below that sink i never touched it . Any help u can offer will be great thanks for ur time

Answer (score 1):

Remove screen on faucet and take apart and clean.  May even have to pull valves on faucets and clean.  During your repairs I would guess you disturbed some crud and stopped up the little water conservators in the tap.  As a old restorationist I see it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by angle stops you mean shut off valves. I would back track from the sink.  Shut off the valves under the sink and remove the lines. Then slowly open the valves to see if you have water pressure. If not, you're going to have to trace the line back and  find the blockage. Obviously take the normal precautions.

Comment: ty but for both hot  and cold to get blocked ..i could see one but both ..ill try that for sure and i was going try from the outside water to attach hose and try to blow it back out that way ..slowly forsure maybe that will unblock but still have to figuyre out whyu it was blocked to begin with ..Thanks for help